# SP2007- possible to link UK spelling to USA spelling to get correct results in Search?

Tags: search

I work at an international organization where the "official" spelling is UK. 
However, SP and Office are all set to USA spelling.

The question is if it is somehow possible to link UK and USA spelled words together so that search comes up with the right results.

Example:
color - colour

If i search for a document with "color" in it, how can I set Search to find documents with "colour" in them too?

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the Thesaurus XML file and add an expansion set for the synonyms you want to create.

1. Start Notepad, and then open a thesaurus file. For information on
   locating and identifying the appropriate thesaurus file, see the
   "Understanding thesaurus files" section.
2. If you are changing the thesaurus file for the first time, remove
   the  comment line that appears at the end of the
   file.
3. Make any changes to the thesaurus file. Add, modify, or delete a
   replacement set or an expansion set.
4. Save the thesaurus file, and then close Notepad.

By default, thesaurus files are created and stored in the following location on the query server: Drive:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\12.0\Data\Config. The thesaurus files from that default location are copied to the following folder location for each instance of the Microsoft Search service that exists on the query server: Drive:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\12.0\Data\Office Server\Applications\\Config, where  is the GUID associated with a particular shared services provider.

The above was refrenced from the following TechNet Article: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361734(office.12).aspx